# My UI disappears with enough click events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've managed to build a React app that returns a new quote without repeating but now the UI disappears with enough click events. Why is my code doing this? In the console I get an object error when this occurs.

```
class QuoteMachine extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quote: fullQuote,
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){ 
      let copy = this.props.quotes.slice();
      let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    this.setState(function(prevState,props){
      if(prevState.quote != copy[index]){
        return {quote: copy[index]}
      }return {
        quote: copy[index+1]}
    })
  }

  render(){
const quote = this.state.quote[0];
const author = this.state.quote[1];
return (
  <div id='quote-box'>

    <div id='text'><h1> <div>{quote}</div> </h1></div>

    <div id='author'><h3> <div>{author}</div> </h3></div>

    <button onClick={this.handleClick} id='new-quote'>New Quote</button>
    <a id='tweet-quote' href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet Me</a>
  </div>
  )
} 
}
const QUOTES = [
["Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.", "Steve Jobs"],
["Good Artists Copy, Great Artists Steal.", "Pablo Picasso"],
["Argue with idiots, and you become an idiot.", "Paul Graham"],
["Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.", "Oscar Wilde"],
["Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.", "Leonardo Da Vinci"]
  ];
const fullQuote = QUOTES[Math.floor(Math.random() * QUOTES.length)]
ReactDOM.render(<QuoteMachine quotes={QUOTES} />, 
            document.getElementById('node'))
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Sure, in the console it logs: [object Error] {}

Answer (score 0):

Is that because your index out of the array of `copy`?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: let's suppose `copy.length` is 10, and then `let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);` . Here ,`index` might be 9, and `index+1` equals to 10. so `copy[10]` is out of range.

Comment: Oh wow that makes a lot of sense. I'll keep working on this and let you know.

Comment: I think you've hit it right on the money. Console logging `index` show's an index out of range of `copy.length`.

Comment: `index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length?-1:+1);console.log(index)
      return {
        quote: copy[index]}
    })` doesn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length),copy.length-1)

Comment: I no longer get an error when clicking but very occasionally a quote does repeat. Thanks for the help!